# Unable set colors according to Terminal's support in .screenrc

Tags: colors, terminal, gnu-screen

I would like to have a if-else loop in **.screenrc** for the following codes such that it is run if my terminal supports 256 colors. Otherwise, it is not run.

```
attrcolor b ".I"
# tell screen how to set colors. AB = background, AF=foreground
termcapinfo xterm "Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm"
termcapinfo xterm-color "Co#256:AB=\E[48;5;%dm:AF=\E[38;5;%dm"
```

**How can you make the if-else loop in .screenrc?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should already be set by the terminfo database file.  In my case my default terminal is xterm.  It uses 8 colors which is reflected in vi by using the

:set termcap

command an inspecting the t_Co item which is set to 8.  If I change my terminal to another terminal type like gnome-256color which uses 256 colors then vi will show t_Co as equal to 256.  I'm not sure why you need to try and set this in your .vimrc file.

Comment: Thank you for the piece of information! Then the only problem is to have a if-else loop in .screenrc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this should work if you have bash available:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$TERM" = "xterm-256color" ]; then
    # do stuff for 256
else
    if [ "$TERM" = "xterm" ]; then
        # do stuff for 16
    else
        # do something else entirely
    fi
fi
```

Comment: My terminal application is OS/X's iTerm. I am not sure whether your code works or not, since I have got no evidence that it works.

Comment: What happens if you "cat $TERM" on OSX?

Answer (score 0):

**My pseudo-code attempt for .screenrc**

```
[ -e t_Co(256) ] . ColorFile
```

The same in English

```
If 256 color support, then source ColorFile.
```